# How to start coding automation for MObile app Webview

Tags: java, selenium, android-webview, appium, appium-android

I am trying to code an automation test for a hybrid mobile app using Selenium and Appium. I have no issues in interacting with elements in the native portion of the app, but it's the webview part that's bothering me. It always hit "Unable to find element" errors using the standard "findElement" (the xpaths,ID etc are otained from Appium's Element inspector). However, when I use the Touchaction objects, it pretty much able to interact with the elements, albeit 90% of time, but I do not wish to use TouchAction. I would like to know, what is the standard way to write code to test Webviews,a s in do I need to create a special function or declare/import any specific libraries ? Yes, google is a popular method, but it does not specifically show the ONE way to kickstart webview-android testing. Thanks. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

[`Appium Desired Capabilities`](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)

Try to put `autoWebview` with `true` value in you capability:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("autoWebview", true);
```

And switch it first to `driver.context("WEBVIEW_1");`

[`Automating Hybrid Apps`](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/)

Comment: Hi @frianH, thanks. I have tried that before, but it will always error at "driver_App = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"),dc); " with the error message "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{appPackage=com.mol.molwallet.uat, appActivity=com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity, noReset=true, automationName=UiAutomator2, autoWebview=true, platformName=Android, deviceName=3RP4C18418001857}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]

Comment: @testerABC You've tried to put `app` capability? As per my understanding, if you want open apps with instruments mode, then you must install the apps with instruments mode too.

Comment: oh this is new to me. Do you mind briefly explain to me what is this "app capability" and how do I get it installed ? Appreciate it.

Comment: @testerABC `caps.setCapability("app", "absolute_path/.../your_app.apk");` it is to install the application.